# Sequence Container OnProgress event handler not firing

Tags: ssis

Im having 2 variables --> "Variable1" which holds "x"(Seconds),"Variable2" is having expression : (DT_I4)DATEDIFF( "ss", @[System::StartTime]  ,Getdate()) 
Im having a sequence container which runs for "y" seconds and will be definetly greater than "x" seconds. for that sequence container im having an OnProgress event handler.
In event handler im having one script task which will compare "variable1" and "variable2".
If variable1= variable2  then returns True or else false.
Main criteria is when sequence container reaches "x" seconds then flag value in below code is set to true and should send email using sendemailtask next to script task.
Issue : Problem is onprogress is not firing.
if the event changed to post/pre execute its firing.. and mails are coming twice.. not once..

Please Suggest !!

Comment: below is the code in script task.
int variable2= (int)Dts.Variables["User::variable2"].Value;
int variable1= (int)Dts.Variables["User::variable1"].Value;
Boolean flag = (Boolean)Dts.Variables["User::Flag"].Value;
flag = false;
if (variable1 == variable2)
{
flag = true;
return;
}
return;

Comment: Sequence container has a script task. for that script task im passing variable1(in seconds) to sleep thread like below

System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(Variable1*1000+20000);

which makes sequece container MUST run greater than time in variable1  which in turn will compare the variable1 and variable2 in event handler script task resulting in TRUE. and send' mail using send mail task